# Compare object in java LinkedList

Tags: java

```
void foo(Item item) {
    LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    items.add(item);
    Item i = items.getLast();
    boolean b = i.equals(item);
}
```

`b` is `false`. I think it should be true. Why?

Comment: Make sure to override the `equals` method in your `Item` class.

Comment: What is `Item`?  How is its `equals()` method defined?

Comment: please post the reproducible code, may be a ideone.com demo

Comment: I just need default equals() method!

Comment: @JusangLee Show us your `Item` class .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot probably you mean the `Item#equals` method (no need to know all the class details...)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `Item#equals()` in case he has overridden the `equals()` method.

Comment: Oh! sorry.. My co-worker overrided equals() method in Item class... ;(

Comment: @JusangLee And the code ???

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Item` class **correctly**. After examining correctly , it seems the default implementation of the `equals()` method provided by the `java.lang.Object` will work in the OP's case.

It seems some faulty implementation of `equals()` in `Item` class is causing this issue.

Comment: just equals will do here, +1

Comment: But the best practice is to override them both .

Comment: The default implementation of `equals()` is fine for the OP's use-case: http://ideone.com/iF6Kvz.  The problem must be that the real `Item` has a silly non-default implementation.

Comment: @JigarJoshi But I read  **if you override equals, you must override hashCode** in java best practices:http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31 ,is it wrong ??

Comment: Based on your current answer state, the problem is in the override of `equals` method that must be broken (which isn't covered here).

Comment: @suresh I meant _here_

Comment: @JigarJoshi Oh. I see.